# Battery Protect Mode: On or Off?

Tags: battery, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Android tablet that I intend to be plugged in 24/7. I have either two options:

1. Battery protect mode OFF: the device will occasionally discharge to 99%, then be charged back to 100%.
2. Battery protect mode ON: the device charges to 60%, then stops, discharges down to 40%, then charges back up to 60%.

Which method actually will prolong my battery life/health in the long-term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lithium-ion batteries are best kept around 50% charge. The number of charge cycles is not that important if you only charge/discharge it around 50%.

**Especially in your case as you want to keep it connected 24/7 the battery protect mode is a perfect match, I strongly recommend to enable battery protect mode.**

Because without this battery protect mode the phone would always charge the battery from about 90% to 100%. Then charging would stop and the battery would drop to 90-95% where charging starts again.

Charging a lithium-ion battery between 90% and 100% is the fastest way to degrade and even destroy it. I also has some devices connected 24/7 which is a real battery kille. I already has quite a few devices with blown-up battery in a way that the device disassembles itself from the inner because of the swollen battery.

Comment: You say the battery will drop down to 90% to 100%, but in my case it's going to be charging 24/7, so wouldn't the battery only very rarely ever have to be used? (only to recharge it periodically after it naturally discharges 1% or so)

Comment: @EH Most devices can not be powered directly via USB, they can only draw power from their battery even while they are powered via USB. So they continuously switch between charging and discharging. Some modern devices at least slow down the charge process if they detect a high number of charge cycles higher than 90% but in the end they are also caught in the charge/discharge cycle.